# Lost receipts in move... what if I'm audited?

Tags: united-states, irs, receipt, audit

I just moved and somehow the box of receipts I use to document expenses in case of an IRS audit was lost.  I have looked and looked, but it's gone.

I have no reason to believe I will be audited, but am now quite nervous about the possibility.

Is there anything I can do preemptively right now other than pray?

Comment: Do you have checks or credit card stayements to show what you spent when and where, if not necessarily what for?  For big items you can sometimes ask the vendor to look it up and regenerate the receipt.

Comment: Definitely would be easier to answer if you explain what things you're talking about expense-wise.  Is this business dinner expenses for your self-employed business?  Is this home repairs?  Medical bills?

Answer (score 2):

If they're receipts for purchases you paid for with a credit/debit card/check, your first idea should be to go to your credit card or bank website and download the statement(s) that cover those expenses.  While that may not be sufficient proof, it is probably better than nothing, and it may give you if nothing else a place to start if the audit comes (as you could identify the vendor, who might be able to print past receipts). That probably isn't possible more than a few months back for most vendors, but who knows.